# Audio file format with metadata supporting tagging?

Tags: audio, metadata, mp3, avaudioplayer, id3

I would like to create a media player reading/writing all music metadata directly from the files. The MP3 format's id3 metadata already has most of the info like *artist*, *song title*, *album name*, but if you want to tag music with custom tags like "atmospheric", "feel-good-music", "road-trip", you need an external database that will attribute tags to filenames.

Is there a music format with reasonable size (not PCM WAV for example) that incorporates metadata including multiple tags? The word "tag" is often used for the *ID3 Tag*, making it difficult to find information on Google about actual tagging, and I only end up with MP3 ID3 pages.

Comment: Maybe look for "keywords" instead of "tags"?  Not that it seems much better.  One option may be to create MP4 audio steam only files.  That would allow for XMP metadata.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MP3 with ID3v2 which has — besides the standard fields you've already mentioned —  support for `TXXX` frames. These frames are a textual mapping between keys and values which allow for arbitrary values stored in the files.

From the [ID3v2 specification](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames)

> 4.2.6.   User defined text information frame
>
> This frame is intended for one-string text information concerning the
>     audio file in a similar way to the other "T"-frames. The frame body
>     consists of a description of the string, represented as a terminated
>     string, followed by the actual string. There may be more than one
>     "TXXX" frame in each tag, but only one with the same description.
>
> ```
> <Header for 'User defined text information frame', ID: "TXXX">
> Text encoding     $xx
> Description       <text string according to encoding> $00 (00)
> Value             <text string according to encoding>
> ```

In your example, a valid `TXXX` frame would use, e.g., `STYLE` as description and `atmospheric` as actual value. If you're on Windows, you can try the Windows player [foobar2000](https://foobar2000.org) and the tag editor [Mp3tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/en/) (full disclosure: I'm the developer of Mp3tag).

Answer (score 0):

Matroska supports most anything.  It has a well-defined set of tags and is also extensible for you to add your own if needed.

https://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/tagging/index.html

It also supports pretty much any codec you throw at it.

Answer (score -2):

Beatunes has columns for tagging mood, color, instrumentation, danceability and more.

https://www.beatunes.com/en/index.html#head

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with the company whose product you linked? Even if not, I don't really see that this answers the question. Rather, it looks more like an advertisement.